# Bolster for level for stealth in < 55 Warzone

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

If I am in a lower level warzone, then all out gear is bolstered. But what about levels re stealth?
If I am 30 and they are 54 is their chance of seeing me like a lvl 55 looking at a lvl 55 or a lvl 54 looking at a lvl 30?

Comment: Good question.  I would assume everyone is made 55 but I don't actually know.

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to spot people significantly higher-level than me in low level warzones (10 or more level gaps); this makes me believe that your effective level in your example would be 55 (60 now) and thus the stealth checks would be that of a level 55 spotting a level 55.

Answer (score 0):

General stealth is equal for all levels, however higher-level players may have stealth and/or detection boosts in their class tree. For instance Infiltration and Scrapper get increases in stealth level, I believe, after their thirties.